# Manage User - Firebase and Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to get a user by email, and it seems to be pretty simple. I am following this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users)

It seems that my code does not recognize `admin`, what it is normal cause I haven't defined anywhere. What I have done is to change `admin` for `firebase`, being firebase:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
```

and the code would be:

```
firebase.auth.getUserByEmail(participantEmail)
```

but I get the following error:

> Property 'getUserByEmail' does not exist on type 'Auth'.ts(2339)

Do I need to pre-install something before? Do I miss something?

My aim is to get the list of all the users' email registered on my system and then filter them, or directly get on a specific user by looking within an email (the second option would be better).

**UPDATE**
Now I am creating a user list each time somebody logs in, but I think that firebase is restricting somehow the information.

*Register*

```
  registerUser(
    email: string,
    pass: string,
    displayName: string,
    photoURL: string
  ) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).then(
        user => {
          resolve(user);
          user.updateProfile({
            displayName: displayName, // some displayName
            photoURL: photoURL
          });
          //NEEDS TO BE INSIDE UPDATEPROFILE
          this.insertUser(user);
        },
        err => {
          this.s_registerError = err.message;
          reject(err);
        }
      );
    });
  }
```

*Insert list*

```
  //Insert a new bet
  insertUser(user) {
    console.log(user);
    console.log(user.email);
    console.log(user.displayName);

    this.listToStore = this.db.list("users");
    this.listToStore.push({
      photoURL: user.photoURL,
      email: user.email,
      displayName: user.displayName
    });
  }
```

in here, I get the value of `user` within all its fields, meaning that when I use `console.log(user)` I am able to see the `displayName`, `email`, and `photoURL`. Nevertheless, If I try to use `console.log(user.displayName)` prints `null` and if I use `console.log(user.email)` prints its value.

I have thought that could be because `user.updateProfile()` did not finish, but actually, I get the value of `user` in `insertUser()` without any problem

Comment: just to make sure: you are using the admin-SDK on a nodejs server and not in a front-end angular project right?

Comment: Not really, I am trying to get the users on my front-end angular project. But I do not really know how to do it. What I want to do is to check if one email is registered in my system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
```

in you client application you are actually importing the [JavaScript SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/) and not the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/). This is the correct way if this import is done in a front-end application, since the Admin SDK is to be used "from a secure server environment".

This is why you get the error `Property 'getUserByEmail' does not exist on type 'Auth'.ts(2339)`, because this method is not part of the Firebase [`Auth`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth) service.

Having said that, you have to know that with the JavaScript SDK there is no straightforward way "to get the list of all the users' email registered on [your] system".

The "usual" way of doing that is to maintain a list of users in your database (RealTime Database or Firestore) and query the database as needed.

Comment: Ok. This is what I thought, but I was trying to avoid starting to create this list. Thanks for the confirmation

Comment: I have updated the question. Could you have a look one second?

Comment: Nothing, it s been solved. I just needed to use  then after update profile and call it from there

Answer (score 1):

Like you have pointed out: `getUserByEmail` is only part of the admin SDK and you will not be able to call that from your Angular code.

If your app is having a concept of finding or managing other users then you might consider that the users are part of your business data. So copy and create profile data when the auth account is created ([you can read more here](https://medium.com/evenbit/create-user-data-for-new-firebase-auth-accounts-c730719b140a)).

You can find more information on what information that is available on the firebase user object [in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.auth.UserInfo).  Just copy what you need and store it in a collection that you can query from your Angular app.

```js
export const createUserDoc = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {
    const firebaseUser = event.data;
    const user = {
        name: firebaseUser.displayName,
        email: firebaseUser.email,
        photoUrl: firebaseUser.photoURL
    };

    return firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(firebaseUser.uid).set(user);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Only Firebase Admin SDK can get user from Firebase Authentication. Admin SDK should only be used in safe environment i.e. backend server.

What you can do is use a Firebase cloud functions [Auth creation trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events) and then write the email address in your Firebase database/ Firestore. 
Then you can [query your database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data) in angular app to filter out users based on email address.

Another option is to have a HTTPS function to which you can send the email address and the function can then use admin sdk to extract user from Firebase authentication.